# Accessing to an input in higher order procedures in scheme

Tags: lisp, scheme, procedure, mit-scheme

I need to understand how can I access to an input of a function which is given to another function as an input.

For example; I have a function called f which simply does `(define f (lambda (x) (if (null? x) #t (car x))))` this. I need to write a function which takes this f as an input and returns another function such that,

-Define a function `(twoback f)` which takes a function f as its input.

-As its output, it should return a new function g which has the following behaviour:

> g(x) = #t if x is the empty list or a list of length 1.
>
> ```
>  = f(y) where y=(cdr x) otherwise.
> ```

And the function will called like this : `((twoback f3) (list #t #f #t #f))`

So actually my question is : How can I access the list given with the function call in the function that I'm going to write(the twoback function) ? Because i need to check whether it is empty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, by currying the `x` parameter. Something like this:

```
(define twoback
  (lambda (f)
    (lambda (x)
      ...)))     ; fill-in with the logic requested
```

The above will define a procedure called `twoback` which receives `f` as parameter, and in turn it will return a new procedure which receives `x` as parameter. This second procedure being returned is the one called `g` in the question, from it you can access both `f` and `x` as you would normally do.

Now just complete the `...` part with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you mean:

```
(define (twoback f)
 (lambda (x)
  (if
   (or (null? x) (null? (cdr x)))
   #t
   (f (cdr x)))))
(define f (lambda (x) (if (null? x) #t (car x))))
```

Comment: bear in mind that this is probably homework, it's frowned upon to give straight answers in this case, you aren't helping the OP by providing the solution to his work with no effort from his part